# POST to external URL (webhook) but redirect to different URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, get

In my form, I am posting the data to an external url that is a webhook. After the user submits and the data is passed to the webhook, I would like to redirect the user to a confirmation page.

My code below is problematic. When the user submits the form, the jQuery does bring the user to the confirmation page, but the form data doesn't trigger the webhook (the data isn't collected). Can someone help with where I'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

> HTML

```
<form action="https://externalurl.com/webhook" method="POST">
     <input id="email" name="email">
     <input id="firstname" name="firstname">
     <input id="lastname" name="lastname">
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> JQuery

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
           window.location.href = "https://www.mypage.com/confirmation";
          }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you posting to the same domain as the one containing the form? Your POST will fail if you are violating Same-Origin Policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a submit button in the form?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry I forgot to include it in my example code but it's now updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any data to the webhook.  Try...

```
$('form').submit(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: {
        "email": document.getElementById('email').value
        // get other fields
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      }
});
return false;
});
```

Or if your actual form is bigger then there are ways to serialize a whole form's data into json.

Edit:
If you want to debug your ajax calls then the network tab of chrome's developer tools will let you see exactly what you are sending to the server, and its response.

Answer (score 0):

If the web isnt in the same domain that the webhook, you must configure the CORS policy in the webhook server or use alternatives like jsonp.